# Что означает символ $ в коде js(react)

Tags: javascript

У меня есть такой код, почему переменные в нем названы через $?

```
import axios from "axios";

const $host = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://localhost:5000'
});

const $authHost = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://localhost:5000'
});
```

Comment: не вызваны.....просто наименование такое......но причины не ясны......для jquery скрипта можно было бы помечать такие элементы, которые выбираются с помощью jquery из DOM

Comment: Иногда так можно называть переменные, чтобы разделить логику. На деле host это то же самое, что $host в вашем примере

Comment: похоже php-шник пересел на js )

Comment: @DaniilLoban не обязательно. мы в компании данные, выбранные через jquery помещаем в пременную, которая начинается с доллара. Так мы можем например различить коллекцию users (просто массива) от $users - коллекция данных из DOM и применить соответствующие методы

Answer (score 2):

Вкусовщина, просто так захотели назвать.

Answer (score 1):

Символ $ разрешон для названий переменных, поэтому константа яваскрипт называется через символ $. Скорее всего это уникальное обозначение для красоты. Имеет тоже самое значение как и переменная из одник только букв.